# How to copy only selected renderings from one to another item using sitecore content editor?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How to copy only selected renderings

[image]

from one to another item using sitecore content editor?

Default "Copy To" function copy all renderings i want to copy and paste only selected.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way to copy a subset of the renderings from one item to another.  I think the two main options to do this would be

1) Copy all of the renderings and go into the presentation settings of the new item and take out the unneeded renderings. (This can be a real pain if you have to do this for a lot of templates)

2) Set the presentation settings on an item how you want it.  Go to Raw Values and copy the whole rendering string, then paste it in the renderings field on the items where it needs to be set.  If you needed to do this for a lot of items it would be pretty straightforward to write a script to put the renderings string in the needed items.

Answer (score 0):

The values you define in Standard Values of the template are reflected exactly the way they are defined (not copied!) This means that if you don't override this field on per item level, the standard value will be used.

If you need the values to be copied to the item, and only selected values, you should consider using [Branch(es)](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/whatsnew-a4.pdf#search=%22branch%22). Hope this helps.